# Solr 4: How to maintain facets after join

Tags: join, solr, faceted-search, facet

I have 2 data types, 'car_dealer' which is a parent of 'car'. Documents of the car-type are indexed including 2 fields 'brand' and 'model'. On these 2 fields I use pivot facetting.

Site visitors need to be able to search both cars and car dealers, where car dealers (parent) can be found by matching car data (child). For this I need a join, and luckily solr 4 supports that. To join 'cars' with 'car_dealers' I add a field called 'dealer' to documents of the car-type, this holds the dealer-id the car belongs to, then I join this with an 'id' field that all documents have.

I came up with the following queries (leaving out irrelevant fields)..

**car search:**

`q={!dismax v=$values qf=$fields}&values=porsche&fields=title^10 body^10&facet=true&facet.pivot=brand,model` (facets work correctly)

**car dealer search:**

`q={!join from=dealer to=id defType=dismax v=$values qf=$fields}&values=porsche&fields=title^10 body^10&facet=true&facet.pivot=brand,model`

This last query shows up the car dealers just fine, but since documents of the car_dealer-type contain no brand or model the facets don't work.

**How can I return the facets also in the car dealer search?** So that people can filter dealers by brand and model.

I tried a reverse join on facet.pivot as local param, but without any luck:

`facet.pivot={!join from=id to=dealer}brand,model`

I'm not sure if its even possible to add local params to facets, i've read all the documentation I could find, but nothing is mentioned about this particular scenario.

Any push in the right direction will be very much appreciated :)